# Angular2: when url is opened from browser notification - target component stops working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When I open a URL by clicking browser notification, the functionality of the page stops working.

I have a small project to demostrate the issue: https://github.com/bdwbdv/quickstart

Normal behaviour: start the application, open project in browser (URL `/cars`), click one of the cars which takes you to a `/car/:id` view, click button "EDIT" - opens an input field with car brand and shows "CANCEL" button.

Abnormal behaviour: start the application, open project in browser (URL `/cars`), click the browser notification "Check out this car (click me)" which takes you to a `/car/:id` view, click button "EDIT" - nothing happens.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you check the browser console to see if there is any error after clicking notification?

Comment: @admax Yes, I keep it open all the time - there are no errors whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get your project to run but your CarComponent class does not implement OnInit even though you have a ngOnInit function within the class.

```
export class CarComponent implements OnInit
```

Same is true of your CarsComponent class.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, I have fixed it now, however `ngOnInit` method was working before, otherwise the app wouldn't even function

Comment: Just to clarify, this change doesn't fix the actual problem described in the question